# Why won't my DSC configuration let me pass a [ref], and what's an alternative?

Tags: powershell, dsc

I'm trying to pass a variable to my DSC configuration, and have it modified inside it, then returned. To do so, I wanted to use a ref var.

Like so in my powershell script:

```
configuration My_DSC_config
{
    param (
        [ref]$data
    )

    Node $AllNodes.Where({$_.Role -eq "test"}).nodename
    {
        #some code....
        $data.Value = 10
    }
    
}

$myVar = 3
My_DSC_config -data ([ref]$myVar) -ConfigurationData <my_config> -OutputPath <mofPath>
Start-DscConfiguration -Path <mofPath> -credential <myCreds>
```

**However, when I start the powershell script, i get an error :**

"New-Object : The argument "2" must not be of type System.Management.Autmation.PSReference. Don't use [ref]."

**Why so? And if using [ref] isn't possible, how can I get a 'global' variable to change inside of my configuration call?**

Comment: You can't. MOF/CIM doesn't have any concept of "global variables" (nor reference variables).

Comment: Too bad, thanks for the reply @MathiasR.Jessen